# Determine the set of solutions $ \arg\left(\frac{z+i}{z-i}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2} $

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

To do determine set of solutions:

$$ \arg\left(\frac{z+i}{z-i}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2} $$

A small approach:

- $ z = x + iy $, $\quad$ where $ x,y \in \mathbb{R} $

Now consider:

$$\frac{z+i}{z-i}=\frac{(z+i)(\bar{z}+i)}{(z-i)(\bar{z}+i)} =\frac{z\bar{z}+i(z+\bar{z})-1}{z\bar{z}+i(z-\bar{z})+1} = \frac{x^2+y^2+i(2x)-1}{x^2+y^2+i(2iy)+1} = \frac{x^2+y^2-1+i2x}{x^2+y^2+1-2y}  $$

So we consider : $$ \arg\left(\frac{x^2+y^2-1+i2x}{x^2+y^2+1-2y}\right) $$
heres the part where I stuck.

I also notice that the denominator $x^2+y^2+1-2y \in \mathbb{R}$ maybe this is an useful information, too?

Comment: **Hint:** You started well... notice that $$\arg(x+iy)=\frac{\pi}{2}\iff x=0\text{ and }y>0.$$

Comment: Denominator is not important for the argument, just observe the numerator. $$\arg\left(\frac{x^2+y^2-1+i2x}{x^2+y^2+1-2y}\right)=\arg\left(x^2+y^2-1+i2x\right)$$

Comment: @user "denominator is not important" provided that the denominator is positive.

Comment: On a personal note, your posting showed good instincts, by resorting to $~z = x + iy,~$ rather than $~z = e^{i\theta}.~$  There are (other) problems that are best attacked via $~z = e^{i\theta}~$ instead.  This is not one of those problems.

Comment: @GEdgar In this case it is equal to $(z-i)(\bar z+1)=|z-i|^2>0$.

Comment: @GEdgar Indeed we also have$x^2+y^2+1-2y=x^2+(y-1)^2>0$. I'm referring to this particular case.

Comment: @GEdgar I agree that in my sentence it wasn't so clear, thanks to have pointed it out.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help/ effort and different approaches in the answer section! May I ask two tiny questions?  at Surb 1. Can you briefly explain why your equivalence holds? 2. @user I hope its not a stupid question, but why exactly can we "ignore" the positive denominator?

Comment: @AsaMitaka Denominator in this case is a positive real number ($=|z-i|^2>0$) and the division of a complex number by a positive real number doesn't change the argument, it is just a scale factor. E.G. $$\arg(2+2i)=\arg\left(\frac{2+2i}{2}\right)=\arg(1+i)=\frac \pi 4$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$w=\frac{z+i}{z-i}=\frac{z+i}{z-i}\frac{\bar z+i}{\bar z+i}=\frac{|z|^2-1+2i\Re(z)}{|z-i|^2}$$

with the conditions

- $\Re(w)=0 \implies |z|^2-1=0$
- $\Im(w)>0 \implies \Re(z)>0$ (since $|z-i|^2>0$)

which lead to the general solution.

---

As an alternative, we have that for $t\in\mathbb R^+$

$$w=\frac{z+i}{z-i}=i\,t \implies z=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}-i\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$

and we recognize the [tangent half-angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula) by $t=\tan \frac \theta 2$ with $0<\theta < \pi$ such that

$$z=\sin \theta-i\cos \theta$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $|z|^2+1 - 2 \Im(z)$ in the denominator? That is what OP already calculated: $$\frac{z+i}{z-i}= \cdots = \frac{x^2+y^2-1+i2x}{x^2+y^2+1-2y}$$

Comment: @MartinR Yes good catch! I fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Set the points $A(-i), B(i), M(z).$ Then $$\arg\left(\frac{z+i}{z-i}\right)=\arg\left(\frac{z_M-z_A}{z_M-z_B}\right)$$ is the oriented angle between the vectors $\vec{MB}$ and $\vec{MA}.$  From

$$\arg\left(\frac{z+i}{z-i}\right)= \frac{\pi}{2}$$
we conclude that the locus of points $M$ is the open half-circumference with extremal points $A,B$ and diameter $AB.$
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach: $z \mapsto \frac{z+i}{z-i}$ is a Möbiustransformation, the inverse mapping is
$$
 w \mapsto S(w) = i\frac{w+1}{w-1} \, .
$$
Möbiustransformations maps lines to circles or lines and are uniquely determined by the image of three distinct points.

Here we have $S(0) = -i$, $S(i) = 1$, and $S(\infty) = +i$, to that the imaginary axis is mapped to the unit circle, and the ray
$$
 \{ w \mid \arg w = \frac \pi 2\} = \{ iy \mid y \in \Bbb R, y > 0 \}
$$
is mapped to the arc on the unit circle that extends from $-i$ to $i$ and contains the point $1$, that is the right semicircle
$$
 \{ z \mid |z| = 1, \operatorname{Re}(z) > 0 \} \, .
$$

Answer (score 1):

To finish the algebraic approach of OP:
$$\frac{x^2+y^2-1+i2x}{x^2+y^2+1-2y}=\frac{(x^2+y^2-1)+i(2x)}{x^2+(y-1)^2}$$
The denominator $$x^2+(y-1)^2>0$$ for $(x,y)\neq (0,1)$ or $z\neq i.$
Thus
$$\arg\left(\frac{x^2+y^2-1+i2x}{x^2+y^2+1-2y}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2} \iff \left(x^2+y^2=1 \quad\text{and}\quad x>0\right)$$ or $$|z|=1 \quad \text{and} \quad \Re({z})>0.$$